# Jquery list update

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have a drag/drop list my problem being I'm trying to detect when a div is dropped via Jquery using mouseup.

The problem being the reason I need to do this is so I can update my lists (in MYSQL) - I plan on doing this using a Jquery Ajax post.

My problem is I've set up the code and I don't know where I am going wrong - in my code you will see an alert function - I used this to show if the div was updating.

So far I am receiving no alert..

Here is the jquery at the moment:

```
$(document).ready(){
$(.mouseup).mouseup(function(){
var divparent = $(this).parent().attr("id");
alert(divparent);
});
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put some arrows where things need to change.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // <-----------------
  $(".mouseup").mouseup(function(){ // <--------------
    var divparent = $(this).parent().attr("id");
    alert(divparent);
  });
}); // <---------------
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :) - can't believe I missed out these small things - remember in future

Comment: We all miss small stuff. It comes with the job/hobby.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have a class named `.mouseup` in your html so you need to make sure jquery knows that.

this line: `$(.mouseup).mouseup(function(){`

should be: `$('.mouseup').mouseup(function(){`

You also don't need the `.ready` check.

If you want to keep the `.ready` @Kyle has it correct.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the `mouseup` event won't fire when you release your mouse away from the original location of the element you were dragging.

One way to solve this is to set the `mouseup` event on the body instead and detect which item you were dragging to begin with.